# Equations in tabularx

Tags: tables, equations, tabularx

I have been trying to display a set of equations in a table using tabularx. However, none of the followings are satisfactory:

- The second row is too tight
- The third row has lots of spacing (I've tried other environments to remove spacing, none of them works. parbox gives a better result though, but not fulfilling either)
- and why both columns are the same size? (using align this will resolve, however spacing won't.)

  ```
   \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\textbf{Species Concentration in the Bulk}} \\
                \hline
                $
                    \left[H{\rm PO}_4^{2-}\right]_h
                $&
                $
                    \frac{{K_{a5}{K_{a6}\left[H_3O^+\right]}_h C}_{bp}}{{\left[H_3O^+\right]_h}^3+K_{a5}\left[H_3O^+\right]_h^2+K_{a5}{K_{a6}\left[H_3O^+\right]}_h +{K_{a5}K}_{a6}K_{a7}}
                $
                \\\hline
                $$
                    \left[{\rm PO}_4^{3-}\right]_h
                $$&
                $$
                    \frac{{{K_{a5}K}_{a6}K_{a7}C}_{bp}}{{\left[H_3O^+\right]_h}^3+K_{a5}\left[H_3O^+\right]_h^2+K_{a5}{K_{a6}\left[H_3O^+\right]}_h +{K_{a5}K}_{a6}K_{a7}}
                $$\\
            \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Using two X type columns inside of tabularx will by default result in two equally wide columns.

Comment: Note that none of your `\left... \right` constructions here does anything relevant. Additionally see the mhchem package for a proper way to write H3O+ (hint they should be upright, mhchem makes that super easy)

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I know there are lots of non-sense terms in the equations, as they have been copied from word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

For above result you need to define different width of columns, use the same math environments (`\displaystyle`) for all math terms and add some vertical space by employing `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.3\hsize$\displaystyle}X<{$}|
                              >{\hsize=1.7\hsize$\displaystyle}OX<{$}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|Ol|}{\textbf{Species Concentration in the Bulk}} \\
    \hline
 \bigl[H\mathrm{PO_4}^{2-}\bigr]_h
    &   \frac{{K_{a5}{K_{a6}\left[H_3O^+\right]}_h C}_{bp}}
             {\bigl[H_3O^+\bigr]_h^3 + K_{a5}\bigl[H_3O^+\bigr]_h^2 +
               K_{a5}{K_{a6}\bigl[H_3O^+\bigr]}_h + 
               {K_{a5}K}_{a6}K_{a7}}
            \\  \hline
\bigl[\mathrm{PO}_4^{3-}\bigr]_h
    &   \frac{K_{a5}K_{a6} K_{a7}C_{bp}}
             {\bigl[H_3O^+\bigr]_h^3 + K_{a5}\bigl[H_3O^+\bigr]_h^2 + 
              K_{a5}K_{a6} \bigl[H_3O^+ \bigr]_h +
              K_{a5}K_{a6} K_{a7}}
            \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: It is not clear what your math-mode symbols/variables mean. Somehow they remind me of chemical formulae. If this is case, then you may consider loading the `mhchem` package` and, for example, replace the term in the first column and row as follows

```
% in preamble
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

 % in the first cell
\ce{[HPO4^{2-}]_h}
```

which gives (the cell with the `\ce` directive is highlighted in yellow):

[image]

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing the `\ce` code a bit. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! Now is much better!

Answer (score 3):

`tabularx`  is designed to control the widths for *linebreaking* in paragraphs in p columns, so is not suitable here, I would use `tabular`. Also all `X` columns are the same width by default, but here you want cells of their natural width.

As a general comment there are packages such as `mhchem` to make entering chemical formual easier, but I did not change that here.  Also, `\rm`  is not defined by default in LaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% only in old latex  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{array,amsmath}
  \newcommand\zfrac[2]{\dfrac{\rule[-5pt]{0pt}{0pt}#1}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{15pt}#2}}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{table}
  \centering
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
          \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|}}
              \hline
              \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Species Concentration in the Bulk}} \\
              \hline
              
                  \left[\mathrm{H}{\mathrm{PO}}_4^{2-}\right]_h
              &
              
                  \zfrac{{\mathrm{K}_{a5}{\mathrm{K}_{a6}\left[\mathrm{H}_3O^+\right]}_h \mathrm{C}}_{bp}}{{\left[\mathrm{H}_3O^+\right]_h}^3+\mathrm{K}_{a5}\left[\mathrm{H}_3O^+\right]_h^2+\mathrm{K}_{a5}{\mathrm{K}_{a6}\left[\mathrm{H}_3O^+\right]}_h +{\mathrm{K}_{a5}\mathrm{K}}_{a6}\mathrm{K}_{a7}}
              
              \\\hline
              
                  \left[{\mathrm{PO}}_4^{3-}\right]_h
              &
              
                  \zfrac{{{\mathrm{K}_{a5}\mathrm{K}}_{a6}\mathrm{K}_{a7}\mathrm{C}}_{bp}}{{\left[\mathrm{H}_3O^+\right]_h}^3+\mathrm{K}_{a5}\left[\mathrm{H}_3O^+\right]_h^2+\mathrm{K}_{a5}{\mathrm{K}_{a6}\left[\mathrm{H}_3O^+\right]}_h +{\mathrm{K}_{a5}\mathrm{K}}_{a6}\mathrm{K}_{a7}}
              \\
          \hline
          \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{document}
```